# MySQL Error while trying to update with select Query for Values

Tags: mysql, sql-update

```
update abc set (id,name)=('3','abcd');
```

Exception is:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near

Comment: Can you verify the correct syntax?  The error trace is pretty unambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

here's the correct syntax of sql update.

```
update abc set id = '3', name = 'abcd' where ......
```

Comment: Hi but i am using this kind of queries everywhere

Comment: @raja so now you know what to do

Comment: @Strawberry,I am trying to run the below mentioned query how can we process that.pls hlp me

Comment: You might want to look at the VALUES option of INSERT... ON DUPLICATE KEY